# Should I remove RAM stickers in a Intel i5 NUC?

Tags: memory, cooling, warranty

Just put together a Intel i5 NUC (NUC5i5RYK) and the Corsair Vengeance DDR3L sticks have some rather big stickers on them. Should I remove them for cooling? But I assume that might/will void warranty.

[image]

The sticker is the whole Vengeance (black) + Serial (white) thing. And given the NUC's poor tiny cooler, I was pondering whether to remove the stickers to help the RAM chill a little more?

Would that help and would it be worth voiding the warranty? Or what's an alternative good cooling system for such a NUC that I plan to occasionally use as a portable dev desktop? So Visual Studio compiling will turn the heat up a bit.

Comment: No;  If Corsair thought the stickers were a a heat issue they wouldn't be used.  Yes; If you remove the only identify mark on the product, you will void your warranty, because there will be no way to track if you are eligible for said warranty.

Comment: I did :-)  I have always removed stuff that got in the way of cooling (and always clean it up after).  Then the freaking things (some vengeance) had a real hardware problem.   Lifetime warrenty, except the terms of the warrenty when I read it were removing the stupid stickers voided the warrenty.   Uhh yea 2 years later the saved stickers are not going back on the way the came off, and that is the end of that.

Comment: @Psycogeek Yeap! You never need warranty until you void it. Murphy is always on duty. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly for preference, but realistically it will make almost zero difference. Your RAM is designed specifically for operating with the appropriate labeling attached.

Honestly I would be more concerned about dust attaching itself to the now unprotected adhesive that once affixed the label. I'm sure that would keep in more heat even!

Comment: Right! Was concerned these stickers won't come off clean... Thanks, will accept this in about 10mins when I'm allowed.